# Is there a way to replace long spaces in print()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a loop and I want to use print() on 1 line only but here it needs long spacing so that the letters are not overwritten from the previous print result, and for that I really need long spacing, but I see it is not neat in my code.

Is there a way to replace long spaces in print()?

```
print('[%s!%s] Failed Scraping                                            '%(M, N), end='\r');
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using the str.format() method or f-strings (formatted string literals).

```
M = "A"
N = "B"
message = "[{}!{}] Failed Scraping".format(M, N)
print(message.ljust(70), end='\r')
```

Comment: The relevant part is using `ljust`.